# Multi Autocomplete in same page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, autocomplete

I want to create multi autocomplete but i can just created single one.
It has to work with different  query.
My code like this.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#arama").keyup(function(){
    data_getir($(this).val());
   });
  });
  function data_getir(aranan)
  {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "web.asmx/oku?aranan=" + aranan, //web service ve methodumuz
      data: "{adres:'complete.ascx'}",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(msg){
        $("#goster").html(msg.d)
      }
    });
  }
  function sec(kontrol){$("#arama").val($(kontrol).html()); $("#goster").html("");}




<div>
  <input id="arama" type="text" style="width:150px; height:20px; font-size:11pt;" />
  <div id="goster"></div>
</div>
```

And js:  jquery-1.2.6.pack.js

How can i use it with another query in same page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just generate a new function and bind it to the other input you want to use as autocomplete field, there's no limit to how many autocomplete you can have in one page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#arama").keyup(function(){
    data_getir($(this).val());
   });

   $("#autocomplete_bis").keyup(function(){
    data_getautocomplete_bis($(this).val());
   });
  });
  function data_getir(aranan)
  {

  }

 function data_getautocomplete_bis(aranan){
 $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "web.asmx/oku?new_query=" + aranan, //web service ve methodumuz
      data: "{adres:'complete.ascx'}",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(msg){
        $("#autocomplete_bis_goster").html(msg.d)
      }
    });
}
  function sec(kontrol){
$("#arama").val($(kontrol).html()); 
$("#goster").html("");
}


<div>
  <input id="arama" type="text" style="width:150px; height:20px; font-size:11pt;" />
  <div id="goster"></div>
  <input id="autocomplete_bis" type="text" style="width:150px; height:20px; font-size:11pt;" />
  <div id="autocomplete_bis_goster"></div>
</div>
```